# Скрыть подсказки словаря клавиатуры

Tags: android, клавиатура

Добрый день!

Есть ли возможность задать настройки в поле ввода для клавиатуры, запрещающие отображение словаря/подсказок?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть. Поиграйте с флагами TextAutoComplete у того EditText'а, о котором пишете.